Download Excel File from API using Volley Library
Am trying to download an Excel file from API using Volley(Android Kotlin)
My Code:
val requestBody = ""
val stringReq: StringRequest =
    object : StringRequest(
        Method.GET, url,
        com.android.volley.Response.Listener { response ->
            hidePregressBar()

            Log.d("API Response",""+response)
        },
        com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            hidePregressBar()
        }
    )

below is the response am getting from API. how to convert it to Excel file?
PK��$��O������������������������������xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml��ێ�F�� C��-̠۫U�"�h�M�h�h�F
D: >���ڞ�r3������s!��|��s���T�u��wY&*��������'�:u�i��Rnݟ�v��~�\�~��R6N+P�[��4�����(��^�J�핽�Eܴ���Օ�q�
D: ��>�8+�^a�!j����TȲ�E��㦍_���P+��\�%Z�j߬UJm�ē�Dv��,P�@�~?UO�dզx�����22�{��z�x21n3��}.��+"��������"�����!��"�}/���(0Cdx��6���m�� ��͏�U{��g���ߙ�ԓc��6}S��v�-ݺ�k���_;���INu���dv86�:�N*��)o^T�O�6ǶFV��wu1�tթ'*�����ǜ�Yٿ�����_�
D: ��G�a$0��#x��@|:B�bF0[!��f�Ħ������(n��F���o������V��ڛW�����x������w�4�x�;�yG�w�I6^��L��!]3��/V�`}��M��/�^��W�Ir?6�<�3��%�<_�������'���D�$"�D�o%"˻B>�@��~j2�Y���2ò��nf.̸��F�[�,{��p���%\�,Q���>w��.�B��"f."���tY"����ß�P�gh�Y�h�ܱ�<��܊[�<�L���h�ܱ7�< ߌ=#�cU��rGz|� lKcKzY�����q��-m=���J4T�H�[��-m��U�У�F�j#fK[�lU"�h�Ѹ�(���
D: �*z��h\b�mikm�J�-.7�k��Dz(m�}�������Q�"Y~������ڈ���H���B9�Q���m���P2JC�`(%��d0���!P2J�@�(%C����!P2J�B�P(
D: %C�d(����P2J�B�P(%àd���aP2J�A�0(%àdB(�J&��   �dB(�J&��   �dB(�J�C�p(%ád8����P2J�C�p(%#�d����P2JF@(%#�d���h��ח���揪���뿆�=և���7մ�[��t�J5R��n�2N�I.�M��:�w�U
D: ���z�T9Jg�l�_6�n�i�ĕ���:�d����,ݺ�[ڇ5?���PK<�r�����������PK��$��O������������������������#������xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels��M��0������Y���t[�[���m,��޾^t`
D: ]�RO����,��q�)x��@���M~0p�7[P��;��gwط͉g��F�)�*�c�q�(v�D�Ⱦl���eLF�?���_�S��tt5���?v����!���>�y�.�Z����ـֿ���EF��Lj]|������PK�j�������3����PK��$��O������������������������!������xl/drawings/worksheetdrawing1.xml��]n�0��U�iZC^�N0�%n�����~�J6i{m�?���nt��Db|#�z��]#�o��(8��`��F\��n��5�ϼ�"�{^��}��ZJV=:�2�Ӵ
D: � ��:�   �IvVΫ�E��{ĸ�&�������Mׄ�5
D: �A��8!�b��f଩�Q=P���3��6�*��)�HB�<    8����R���_���O�,�Czȇ�&^��eFwh��ȸ8��ݱ*�6�(+l�^ޭ̳"�_PKbi���������PK��$��O������������������������������docProps/app.xml�RAn�0|A� �SJ��0(��"�5`'=o��E�"   �V���R2��
D: z�m83��+Ld��E�*E�ބ��C-��_n>��|.x��  I��wj�B���� �j�1ǵ�d:�VY�YiC��1dh[k�!�_=z��ey'���ln�(Ή��7�   f�G��S�yZmB���V;7Y�-8B%_    ��0�{6�V�4R�ǤZ�,x�#����V�mgv�.'�#����\� ^z/����ɐ��Q.E2����쐾�[H�����s�J\t܍��7�����j�=�}x���yvפ�u���_��v!�cn����t��̞�����8���fM
D: Z.>
D: :%/���|�]]ݭ��e9fN��5���PK���k���������PK��$��O������������������������������docProps/core.xml���n�0��`�@zm����&n�j&K�ewM9h3Z��y�T������ے-����:��ф�hJ��9zݬ�9����u�!G8�(�2a�h,<�ƀ�\D�1ar���0��؁�.  �a�X�}x�[l���[�BfX��%���،FtR�bT���A)0Ԡ@{�iB���*ws��\�J���M�����l�6i�
D: �)~_?�[���J��*�S&,pe�8���*&��ǔ�$ݐ9#)��>2�g}/<>7�X�Ø�G�plm׳c��K͝_��$��&Ʋ����m�,�^�=�a����PK�V}�6����l����PK��$��O������������������������������xl/theme/theme1.xml�Yˎ�6�����D�-�1�'�3i3��I�,i��S�@R3c�d�M�i�M��(�h���cHЦQ�a���$m�>���X$Ͻ<��<W�\�rp��4�Z�K�P����'a׺s2�k[����u�9�֕��.�}�i��}ص"!�}����MQ"Ǧ��P�&��3�6&v�q�vqbU��u��t�}4�~�D�N"PH�<�)�@c��f'9A�`AuDPn����c��Z�`V���r!��S|,p
D: Iג�� :�}p�^a�Ͷ���Y��c�$7,p����������F�Qs���@ߗ+�m`�~�?�*�*/


How do you know it's not an excel file? Your dump could be a zip file and afaik ms office stores its files zipped.

@Robert As i discussed with backend team they mentioned its a ByteArray data. i need to convert this to Excel file.

Ok, my point was: it could be an excel file. What happens if you just save it to a file and then open that file in excel?

@Robert In Excel sheet also its showing same like above data.
